# Set universal app iPhone only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I have an app on AppStore, it's already universal. Can I set in next version iPhone only? Or how I can set it to run on iPad like on [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKWE4.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried updating an app from supporting `iPad & iPhone` to `iPhone only`, but here's what I know:

Apps that supports iPhone only can still be downloaded on iPads, and will appear like the one shown in your [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKWE4.png). However, that's for `iOS 6` (and probably older). For newer systems like iOS 8 or 9, the view will be resized to fit the full screen, and you cannot choose whether to display `1x` or `2x`.

Thus assuming that upgrading from `universal` to `iPhone only` works, which means not being rejected by Apple, your app will appear in full screen on newer iPads.

Hope my explanation helped.